# What is a flat Kan fibration?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

What is the Kan fibration analog of a connection? of being `flat'?
A Kan fibration is the simplicial analog of a topological fibration.
What structure on a Kan fibration is the simplicial analog of  SMOOTH FIBRATION?

Comment: Is there a reason you are asking here and not at Mathoverflow? In the current form, your question is off-topic at math.stackexchange. I also would much rather answer it (to the best of my capacity) on MO than here.